# How to use the --max-concurrent-uploads flag on docker windows?

Tags: docker, upload

I've been trying to do `docker push --max-concurrent-uploads ...` and `docker --max-concurrent-uploads` but doesn't seem to work.

How can I use it?

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

I can do it from the UI, but I'd like to do it from the `docker push` command.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For Windows 10 Enterprise. My file was in following path. and it worked as well.

C:\Users\{username}\.docker\daemon.json

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "max-concurrent-uploads": 2
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- open c:\programdata\docker\config\daemon.json
- add an entry

```
"max-concurrent-uploads": x
```

- restart docker
- more information can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

As stated in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/, it's a daemon option.