# Docker : "error pulling image configuration: unknown blob"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerhub

OS: Linux Ubuntu

Version: 19.10

Docker Version: 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c

I created a simple docker file like below:

```
FROM busybox:latest
CMD echo Hello World
```

After that, I run the following command to build the docker file:

```
docker build 
-t rshtishi/hello-world-dockerfile
-f HelloWorld.df 
.
```

Then I published in my account on DockerHub:

```
docker push rshtishi/hello-world-dockerfile
```

All the steps above completed successfully. After delete the rshtishi/hello-world-dockerfile images locally I couldn't pull the image from dockerhub.
When I run the pull command I got the error below:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from rshtishi/hello-world-dockerfile
61c5ed1cbdf8: Already exists 
error pulling image configuration: unknown blob
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028844/github-packages-docker-error-pulling-image-configuration-unknown-blob?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It is not duplicate. In my environment, this error is thrown only for the images I have deleted locally. For other images that I haven't deleted the locale images, it works perfectly.